# Where to find the size limit for installing .apk

Tags: applications, apk

You can install new app on your Android device using apk files. Those apk files however must be below a size limit.

Where can I find out this limit?

Comment: APK files are ZIP files, and the older ZIP format was limited to 2GB files. I am not sure if Android supports APK/ZIP files larger than 2GB. Typically an APK file does not get that large because Google Play Store has a size limit, but that has nothing to do with an APK file size limit. This ist just a limitation set by Google without technical reason.